# Android Emulator Network Issues

Tags: android, android-emulator

We have an issue where an application we are developing cannot hit certain environments when ran through the Android Emulator program. However, if we hit one of those same URLs in the Android Emulator Web Browser (chrome for instance), we can hit the pages just fine. Does anyone know how network traffic is handled in the emulator, and if there is anywhere to see if the emulator is just bridging my NIC?